# Cloudera Hue Web UI Default password

Tags: cloudera-cdh, hue, cloudera-manager, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have downloaded Cloudera CDH 5.3 recently and now i am in need to access the HUE Web UI Portal. When i give the default username and password which belong to Cloudera admin/admin it is not working. I am unable to login to the HUE portal now. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're trying to use the Quickstart VM (you tagged your question with the quickstart vm tag), you have to use cloudera/cloudera :)

Answer (score 2):

To reset the admin password, run this from the command line.

/usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue  createsuperuser

or:

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue createsuperuser

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset password for Cloudera Manager managed hue service, you can login to the VM where your Hue service is running and run the following command :

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/YOUR_CDH_VERSION_HERE/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue createsuperuser --cm-managed
```

In my case it was :

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.1.1-1.cdh6.1.1.p0.875250/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue createsuperuser --cm-managed
```

Notice the trailing part of command  (--cm-managed) which is essential (at least for latest version of Cloudera Manager).

Once you run this command it will ask use to set up the new username and password.

That's all. happy Hue'ing :)

Answer (score -3):

The defaults are:

Username : demo
password : demo